# SpriteNode behind UIImages

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uiimage, skspritenode

I've created a SpriteNode in a scene and it's there, but it is stuck behind all the UIImages and UIButtons I've dragged onto the storyboard.

I tried changing the `.zPosition` of the spriteNode to 99999999999999, but it doesn't matter.

What do I need to do to get the spriteNode to appear in front of most of the images? Or can I only have one background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, this is impossible. You are combining two rendering hierarchies (UIKit and Sprite Kit) whose children (UIView and SKNode, respectively) do not mingle.

SKNodes are rendered inside the SKScene that contains them. The final rendered image is used as the image for the layer of the owning SKView. From there, UIKit (and CoreAnimation) composite the UIViews.

A hierarchy for illustration purposes:

- UIView

  - UIButton
  - UIButton
  - SKView (renders an SKScene object)

    - SKNode
    - SKLabelNode
    - SKLabelNode
  - UIImageview

Comment: So do I have to add everything programmatically in the SpriteKit Scene?  Or can I ever drag and drop images?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use Sprite Kit Scene files (.sks), which are like .xibs only for Sprite Kit. You can setup nodes and sprites in this file using Xcode. You can create a new Sprite Kit Scene with Xcode (under New File -> iOS -> Resource -> SpriteKit Scene).